# Symfony 1.4 - .gitignore doesn't working in some ceses

Tags: symfony-1.4, gitignore

I am using Symfony 1.4 in my project. I have .gitignore file that working in this configuration.

```
config/databases.yml
apps/erp/config/factories.yml
.buildpath
.project
.settings
.idea
.DS_Store
.rsync_cache
catalog.xml
config/databases.yml

log/*
cache/*
web/uploads
web/pdf_files
web/knp_sn*
data/sql/*.sql
```

But I don't know how to ignore every dir that name are `map` and `om` in `lib/model/` directory.
[image]

I have inside `lib/model` around 50 folders, and each contains `map` and `om` dir that schould be ignored

This configuration `/lib/model/*/om` `/lib/model/*/map` doesn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. I had to add slash at the end of line 
`/lib/model/*/om/`
`/lib/model/*/map/`